# Is there a SQL query or procedure in Oracle 11g doing the same as Neo4j Cypher query in order to filter shortestpath?

Tags: oracle, neo4j, shortest-path

I got an old sever with oracle 11g.
There is a relationship/edge table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Graph (
   PA VARCHAR (5), 
   PB VARCHAR (5), 
   Distance INT,
   Type VARCHAR (5) ,
   ) 
 
INSERT INTO Graph VALUES 
('A', 'B', 1,'ordered'), 
('B', 'C', 1,'promised'), 
('C', 'A', 1,'helped'), 
('A', 'E', 1,'hired'), 
('E', 'A', 1,'ordered'), 
('D', 'B', 1,'hired')
```

[image]

In neo4j the query like

```
MATCH p=shortestpath((a)-[r*1..3]-(p)) where a<>p and a.name="A" RETURN p,p.length
```

The result might be like

```
Path(varchar)                  Length(int)
A<-ordered-E                   1
A-ordered->B                   1
A-ordered->B<-hired-D          2
A<-helped-C                    1
```

i.e.

1.It's different from `shortestpath((a)-[r*1..3]->(p))`.

2.Limit the max length of path `between 1 and 3`.

3.Show the route with relationship type using string and shortest path length using int.

Is there any elegant and efficient way in oracle to do this?
Maybe `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` but how to generate the path string with relationship type?

Comment: It is possible, but 1. I left Oracle behind for Neo4j because it was convoluted and slow  2. Oracle has their own $$$$ product if you want to do "graphy" db work (with Oracle products).  https://www.oracle.com/database/graph/

Comment: Which means I have to deploy another neo4j server in our old production env and those old db operation engineers would not like it... My next question is how to generate these path output in Neo4j. The default path output is something like `[{"name":"Keanu Reeves","born":1964},{"roles":["Neo"]},{"tagline":"Wel│
│come to the Real World","title":"The Matrix","released":1999}]   ` is much harder to read than `A-roles->B`

Comment: It is harder to read. Partly because it contains a lot more data. Neo4j’s cypher, especially in combination with a good front end ( we have one but there are others too) offers you many options

Comment: Any open source suggestion for `A-roles->B-actor->C` without front end?, I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523029/get-path-in-text-format-from-graph) but it failed to work due to old cypher statement.